# How to create a volume group that is larger than 2 TB on a non-GPT system?

Tags: linux, centos, lvm

I've recently setup a CentOS 6 x64 server with 4x 3TB drives, running on top of a RAID-10 array.

Current partition schema is as below;

```
/boot 500M (Standard ext4)
vg_root 10G (LVM)
swap 12G (Standard)
rest unpartitioned
```

How may I create a single VG that occupies the whole remaining space, that is around 5.5TB?

Comment: I do not see why MBR layout would be the limitation for VG creation. Elaborate more in your question. Show problems you have encountered.

Comment: Check out this https://www.linuxsysadmins.com/tag/logical-volume-management/

Answer (score 1):

On a MBR disk the maximum partition size is limited to 2TB,therefore you would have to create several partitions <= 2TB to split up the remaining space and put them together again as LVM.
In you example there is only one primary partition left to create and an extended partition is also limited to 2TB which wouldn't solve your problem.

The better solution would be to use a GPT labeled disk. Any reasons for not using this?
Also, some hardware RAID controllers support "partitioning" of the RAID array which and these "artition" appear as single disks in the operating system.
Depending on the distribution/version and GRUB version used, you also create 3 equally sized partitions, configure them as PV with `pvcreate`, configure one VG with `vgcreate` and single LVs using `lvcreate`.

Comment: I think I should use vgextend to combine these multiple partitions together, right? At that point, I have been unable to create multiple <=2TB partitions using fdisk, is that normal? (When I've created a primary 4th partition with a size of 2TB, it didn't let me to create an extended one as it supposed to be. When I've created an extended partition instead, I was unable to change it to LVM.) How should I go ahead with creating these multiple partitions? Also, would such a situation - multiple partitions, one volume group - cause any performance degradation?

Comment: Just tested on my own in a VM and I was wrong with the above answer as the extended partition is also limited to 2TB on a MBR disk. I have edited the answer.